# Is it possible to ignore a docking station's power supply, if plugged in to laptop charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, docking-station

I recently purchased a new docking station ([Plugable ud-ultc4k](https://plugable.com/products/ud-ultc4k)) for use with my work laptop ([Dell Precision 5760](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/precision-17-5760-laptop/precision-5760-setup-and-specifications/power-adapter?guid=guid-2ea7ebaa-0143-4c05-803f-5015bfcb4e67&lang=en-us)). The docking station is able to provide up to 100W of power, whereas my laptop can draw up to 130W of power.

I have two problems with this configuration:

- First, I have read that receiving power from a lesser-than-designed source can slow your computer's processing down.
- Second, after about a half day's use, I realized my computer was about to die because it had been trying to charge off the docking station; since I was unable to get the laptop to recognize its designed charger, I was forced to revert to an old power-less docking station and eliminate one screen.

Is there a setting I can change to always force this laptop to charge from its correctly-powered charger while being connected to this underpowered dock for the displays and extra connectors the dock provides?

Comment: This will be mostly dependent on the design of the system's power system, and the dock. You could try looking through the UEFI/BIOS settings to see if there's something that allows the laptop to charge from the charger while it is connected to the dock as well. But ultimately, the best solution is to get a dock that is appropriately sized for your computer.

Comment: Also, you don't list two questions. You make some observations about things you've heard, but you don't actually ask a question for at least one of those. Your own experience proves what you heard is not necearily true for your computer. The laptop used the battery to maintain processing capability when it was not receding sufficient energy from the dock.

Comment: Try connecting the charger first with the dock disconnected, then connect the dock. In that case the computer might ignore the lower power from the dock.

Comment: @harrymc, thank you. This is a suggested workaround I have come across, which so far has been working today. However, I am specifically wondering if there is a setting that would enable me to effectively set it, and forget it so that I have the flexibility to unplug/plug in my charger and/or Dock.

Comment: “First, I have read that receiving power from a lesser-than-designed source can slow your computer's processing down.” This is nonsense. This doesn’t happen.

Answer (score 1):

The dock doesn't have any setting or other means of stopping it from
charging the laptop. On the other hand, the laptop doesn't have any way
of disabling USB-C power-delivery, as these ports are always two-ways.

I can only suggest a workaround, which is to connect the charger
first with the dock disconnected, and only afterward connect the dock.

In many cases, the laptop will ignore the fewer power coming
from the dock and will keep on charging from the charger.

I don't know of a way to change this behavior (and one might perhaps
not exist).